# Return SQL Sub Query with a variable inside Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Application is a cash register.  The following query takes a TransactionID and returns one or more rows of items sold in this single transaction i.e. for TransactionID = 28715:

```
DECLARE @SalesItems varchar(250);
DECLARE @TransactionID int;
SET @TransactionID = 28715;


Select @SalesItems = coalesce(@SalesItems + ', ', '') + CAST(TransactionsPosLines.Description as varchar(250))
From
  TransactionsPosLines
  where TransactionsPosLines.TransactionId = @TransactionID

select @SalesItems
```

and returns:

```
"Widget A,  Widget B, Widget C" as a single string.
```

I also have an end of day transaction report which I want to append the string (Widget A etc...) onto the end of the transaction report.

```
        Select
          Transactions.TransactionId,
          Transactions.TransactionDate,
          Transactions.MoneyIn,
          Transactions.MoneyOut,
          Transactions.Description,
          PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodName,
          Transactions.TransactionRef,
          Membership.Username,
          Tills.Description As 'Till Name',
          Transactions.Reason,
    -- FOR THIS LAST COLUMN HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE OUTPUT OF THE QUERY ABOVE
====>     SalesItems
        From
          Transactions Left Outer Join
          Tills
            On Transactions.TillId = Tills.TillId Inner Join
          PaymentMethods
            On Transactions.PaymentMethodId = PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodsID Inner Join
          Membership
            On Transactions.UserId = Membership.UserId Inner Join
        Where
          Transactions.TransactionDate >= @DateStart And
          Transactions.TransactionDate <= @DateEnd
```

So when I run this report I get something like this:

```
TransactionId   TransactionDate MoneyIn MoneyOut    Description PaymentMethodName   TransactionRef  Username    Till Name   Reason   SalesItems
28715   31/08/2016 09:07    119.99  0   Sale - Card Card    24881   Chantal Till1  Null   Widget A, Widget B, Widget C
```

Comment: Huh???? This doesn't make any sense to me at all. Variables are scalar, they can't hold multiple values. And you can't assign a variable a value like that in the middle of a query. As posted, this is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange that variable assignment does work:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68089/how-to-use-coalesce-with-multiple-rows-and-without-preceding-comma

Comment: @Matt look closer, one column in the select statement is assigning a variable and the others are returning values in the result set. That does NOT work. Sure you can use a select statement to assign values to a variable but not in the context posted here.

Comment: I am trying to group the output of the 2nd query in this column.  The 2nd query can return multiple rows and I am sure this is a simple edit to the code above to acheive this.

Comment: But you can't mix this assignment in the middle there. And the fact that your subquery can return multiple rows means the value would contain the last value in the result set. The way you have this just isn't going to work like that. If you could explain clearly what you are really trying to do here we can help. cross apply may be part of the answer but it just isn't clear what the desired result is.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree to that point that he cannot assign the variable like he is mixing in the top query.  I just thought the way you wrote your comment that you where saying the variable is scalar so you could not use that technique to populate it, but it can be populated like that just not in the middle of the other query as you say

Comment: I have re-edited my question which I hope is a lot clearer, your help would be much appreciated

Comment: There is standard solution using `for xml path('')`. See for example [here](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Converting%20row%20values%20in%20a%20table%20to%20a%20single%20concatenated%20string.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CROSS APPLY WITH FOR XML CONCATENATION METHOD:

```
Select
    t.TransactionId,
    t.TransactionDate,
    t.MoneyIn,
    t.MoneyOut,
    t.Description,
    p.PaymentMethodName,
    t.TransactionRef,
    m.Username,
    tl.Description As 'Till Name',
    t.Reason,
    c.SalesItems
From
    Transactions t
    LEFT JOIN  Tills tl
    ON t.TillId = tl.TillId
    INNER JOIN PaymentMethods p
    ON t.PaymentMethodId = p.PaymentMethodID
    INNER JOIN Membership m
    On t.UserId = m.UserId
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST(tp.Description AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM
            TransactionPostLines tp
        WHERE t.TransactionId = tp.TransactionId
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'') as SalesItems) c
Where
    t.TransactionDate >= @DateStart
    AND t.TransactionDate <= @DateEnd
```

AS Sub Select in column Definition:

```
Select
    t.TransactionId,
    t.TransactionDate,
    t.MoneyIn,
    t.MoneyOut,
    t.Description,
    p.PaymentMethodName,
    t.TransactionRef,
    m.Username,
    tl.Description As 'Till Name',
    t.Reason,
    STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST(tp.Description AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM
            TransactionPostLines tp
        WHERE t.TransactionId = tp.TransactionId
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'') as SalesItems
From
    Transactions t
    LEFT JOIN  Tills tl
    ON t.TillId = tl.TillId
    INNER JOIN PaymentMethods p
    ON t.PaymentMethodId = p.PaymentMethodID
    INNER JOIN Membership m
    On t.UserId = m.UserId
Where
    t.TransactionDate >= @DateStart
    AND t.TransactionDate <= @DateEnd
```

Note using table aliases makes the code easier to read and to write!

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Exactly what I was after.   Which method would be the best (or correct) way to do this?

Comment: that is more a personal preference.  some say use CROSS APPLY because it makes your intent more known and shows the relationship in the from section but really it shouldn't matter you can look at execution plans but I would assume they would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have used cross apply in order to apply result to inner query to each row of your main query. Check whether this helps you:

```
Select
      Transactions.TransactionId,
      Transactions.TransactionDate,
      Transactions.MoneyIn,
      Transactions.MoneyOut,
      Transactions.Description,
      PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodName,
      Transactions.TransactionRef,
      Membership.Username,
      Tills.Description As 'Till Name',
      Transactions.Reason,
-- HERE >>
      --SalesItems = 
      dt.salesItems
    From
      Transactions Left Outer Join
      Tills
        On Transactions.TillId = Tills.TillId Inner Join
      PaymentMethods
        On Transactions.PaymentMethodId = PaymentMethods.PaymentMethodsID Inner Join
      Membership
        On Transactions.UserId = Membership.UserId 
        cross apply (
    select distinct stuff((
    Select  ',' + CAST(TransactionsPosLines.Description as varchar(250)) 
From
  TransactionsPosLines
  where TransactionsPosLines.TransactionId = Transactions.TransactionId
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as salesItems 
  ) as dt
    --  TransactionsPosLines
    --    On TransactionsPosLines.TransactionId = Transactions.TransactionId
    Where
      Transactions.TransactionDate >= @DateStart And
      Transactions.TransactionDate <= @DateEnd
```